# The languages with the most complicated grammars

Tags: grammar

It looks like Navajo has a very difficult-to-tease-apart verb morphology, as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusional_language):

> Unusually for a natively North American language, Navajo is sometimes described as fusional due to its complex and inseparable verb morphology.

Wondering what languages are the most difficult to find standard structure in. Where everything seems irregular or difficult to classify. Or something along those lines.

Comment: Judging by the example provided by the linked Wikipedia article, most European languages, including my own, appear to be fusional. There is nothing even remotely irregular or difficult about them. Basically, one can count to 36 by using two symbols (01-36), or by using one symbol (0-9, A-Z). In both cases, each number is uniquely represented in a very regular and simple manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One rule of thumb in linguistics is that no (modern) language is more or less complex than any other. Certain aspects might vary in complexity—Mandarin Chinese has almost no morphology, for example, while Classical Latin has almost no syntax—but simplicity in one area always corresponds to complexity elsewhere.

The two main areas generally referred to informally as "grammar" are syntax and morphology: syntax is anything bigger than a single word, while morphology is anything smaller. And if one of these is especially complex, the other tends to be especially simple. Navajo, like Classical Latin, is a fusional language: it has dense little morphemes containing lots of information each, and a large number of verb aspects and modes. However, its syntax is relatively simple, with many sentences not being so much a tree as a single node. And while the verbs are immensely complex, the noun morphology is even simpler than in English.

If you're looking for languages with lots of irregularities in particular, look for ones in the middle of some sort of transition. Ancient Greek, for example, has annoyingly unpredictable verb morphology as it's in the process of transitioning to a more fusional model. Classical Latin is further along in the process, and modern Italian has mostly completed it, simplifying the verbs into a nice regular system.

Comment: So it sounds like Modern Italian would be the best for learning about complex morphology (not sure how Italian relates to Spanish/French), while Modern Chinese would be best for learning about complex syntax, and Ancient Greek for learning about significant irregularity (or perhaps Modern German I feel like I read somewhere, I don't know). Would be interested to know if that is correct, or if there are better ones, or if there is anything else in addition which should be considered.

Comment: Also, what seems to be missing from this list is agglutination (e.g. Turkish) and polysynthesis (e.g. Inuktitut). Wondering what they teach best (morphology, probably, (but maybe not better than Italian), instead of syntax. Or perhaps something else).

Comment: P.S. I already know Spanish so if it's pretty much the same as Italian in terms of being an ideal representation of morphological complexity, that would be good to know too!

Comment: Ah so the two scales perhaps are (morphological -> syntactical), then (analytic -> isolating -> fusional -> agglutinative -> polysynthetic), so I'm probably mixing that up. But I wonder why Italian, being fusional, would be better at demonstrating morphology than a polysynthetic language.

Comment: I think the rule of thumb (assuming it's meaningful at all given the difficulty of comparing complexity of different types) is wrong. One need only compare two of the languages you mention, Latin and Ancient Greek -- very similar in overall structure, but Greek has more complexity (more irregularity, more categories) in just about any part of the grammar you look at.

Comment: @LancePollard The syntax of Modern Chinese is no more complex than English. What makes Chinese hard to learn are tones, the abundance of homophones, and the writing system.